# Using OpenLayers 5.3 in TypeScript without Node.js

Tags: openlayers, typescript

I would like to use the latest version of OpenLayers (5.3) in small project. The requirements are:

- no Node.js - I will be running thing on the site hosted on IIS, simple HTML files
- scripts need to be written in TypeScript
- List item
- ES5

I've read a lot of different discussions and I'm a bit confused. It this even possible? The new OpenLayers has `ol` npm package, there are (at least two) types definitions for OpenLayers but I can't get it to work in the browser.

First, it complaining about `import` statements which are not recognized. The other issues are that even if I will include full `ol.js` I can't get typings to work in TypeScript.

Does anyone have some successful examples?

Fo example bellow the `ol` namespace is not recognized:

```
/// <reference path="ol.js"/>
/// <reference path="../Typings/ol/Map.d.ts"/>

// no imports as they are not working without Node.js

class MainMap {

    createMap() {
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
                zoom: 4
            })
        });
    }    
}

let map = new MainMap();
map.createMap();
```

Anyone is successful with using OpenLayers typings in TypeScript without using Node.js?

Comment: Here is a compiler with docs https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile , I don’t see any reason to use ts like that though.

Comment: That was not the goal of my question. I know how to compile TypeScript - that is quite obvious that it needs to be compiled. Above code is just an example, my TS scripts will be much bigger so that I see a lot of reasons of using TypeScript (e.g.: because I can use classes). The main problem is that the TS typings are generaed for `ol` npm package (for for big `ol.js`) and they are not working in my TS files.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 type definitions for openlayers. I use both `@types/ol` and `@types/openlayers`. The latter has a lot more definitions mapped directly to their corresponding modules in the openlayers library.

In most cases your import statement depends on your compiler/tsconfig options. For instance, you would normally use a statement like `import * as <name> from <module>;` with typescript, unless you set `"esModuleInterop": true` in your tsconfig, in which case you can use statements like `import <name> from <module>;`

You could/should also specify the `typeRoots` configuration in your `tsconfig` compiler options. Typically, it would look like this

```
"typeRoots": [
      "<path to custom types that you might have>",
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],
```

[Typescript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab is an example of a project that uses Typescript and OpenLayers and React without Webpack and without OpenLayers typings. It imports the OpenLayers source directly.  It does require using an AMD module loader.  See https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/tsconfig.json for details:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2020", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "amd", /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "jsx": "react", /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "jsxFactory": "create",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "outFile": "./built/index.js",
    "strict": false,
    "paths": {
      "@ol/*": [
        "./node_modules/ol/src/*"
      ],      
      "rbush/rbush.js":["./node_modules/rbush/index.js"],
      "quickselect":["./node_modules/quickselect/index.js"],
      "pbf": [
        "./pbf.js"
      ],      
      "ieee754": [
        "./ieee754.js"
      ],
    }
  },
  "files": ["./index.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "./built/*"
  ],
}
```

Here is my [package.json](https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/package.json) at the time of this writing, where some modules are not yet ported to EJS:

```
{
  "name": "react-lab",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Typescript + TSX + React + RequireJS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "ol": "^6.4.3",
    "simplify-geojson": "^1.0.3",
    "terser": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

I was luck enough to find rbush/index.js, which is an javascript module.  I load that instead of rbush.js using the "paths" option.  I did the same for quickselect.  I was not so luck with pbf and ieee754, both of which use a non-compatible module syntax.  It was trivial to port them.

- https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/pbf.js
- https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/ieee754.js

Now I can produce a index.js and index.js.map containing all the parts of openlayers that I imported and nothing more and thanks to the ol developers the modules I do import are strongly typed, even though they are js files.  Here is a snippet from https://github.com/ca0v/react-lab/blob/master/components/openlayers.tsx:

```
import Map from "@ol/Map";
import VectorSource from "@ol/source/Vector";
import VectorLayer from "@ol/layer/Vector";
import Geometry from '@ol/geom/Geometry';
import type GeometryType from '@ol/geom/GeometryType';
import { GeoJSON } from '@ol/format';
import View from '@ol/View';
import { fromLonLat } from "@ol/proj";
import * as interaction from "@ol/interaction";
import type MapBrowserEvent from '@ol/MapBrowserEvent';
import Feature from '@ol/Feature';
import type Collection from '@ol/Collection';
import type { Coordinate } from '@ol/coordinate';
import BingMaps from "@ol/source/BingMaps";
import XYZ from "@ol/source/XYZ";
import OSM from "@ol/source/OSM";
import TileLayer from "@ol/layer/Tile";
import TileSource from '@ol/source/Tile';
import { Extent, getCenter } from '@ol/extent';
import Zoom from "@ol/control/Zoom";
import ZoomSlider from "@ol/control/ZoomSlider";
import FullScreen from "@ol/control/FullScreen";
import MousePosition from "@ol/control/MousePosition";
import Rotate from "@ol/control/Rotate";
import ScaleLine from "@ol/control/ScaleLine";
import ZoomToExtent from "@ol/control/ZoomToExtent";

const ol = {
    interaction,
    control: 
    {
        ScaleLine,
        Rotate,
        MousePosition,
        FullScreen,
        Zoom,
        ZoomSlider,
        ZoomToExtent,
    },
    source: {
        XYZ,
        OSM,
        Vector: VectorSource
    },
    layer: {
        Vector: VectorLayer
    }
};
```

It is important to realize I am not using openlayers typings but actually importing the openlayers source code.  If you setup tsc in watch mode re-compiles are pretty quick.  it is also important to realize I am not using webpack or rollup to do this.  This is pure typescript transpiling.